# Smartphoto.js how to track objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Faced with such a challenge. There is a gallery to view photos, as a plug-in used [Smartphoto.js](https://appleple.github.io/SmartPhoto/), the gallery works and everything is fine, but you need to make sure that the bottom elements are tracked together super. That is, as soon as the last bottom element comes to the end you need to show it, now it is hidden, how can you solve this problem?

[image]

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  new SmartPhoto(".gallery-article", {
    useOrientationApi: true,
    resizeStyle: 'fit'
  });
});
```

```css
.article__gallery-images {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.article__gallery-images a img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}


/* style gallery */

.smartphoto {
  z-index: 99999999 !important;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) !important;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.smartphoto-body {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 102;
  max-width: 55vw;
  height: 80vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #fff;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.smartphoto-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 101;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.smartphoto-list li {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.smartphoto-img-wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 75px);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out;
  -webkit-animation-name: smartphoto-img-wrap;
  animation-name: smartphoto-img-wrap;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.3s;
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  transform: none !important;
}

.smartphoto-inner {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.smartphoto-list li {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.smartphoto-list li img {
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.smartphoto-count {
  display: none !important;
}

.smartphoto-caption {
  display: none !important;
}

.smartphoto-header {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.smartphoto-dismiss {
  background-image: url(../images/icon/close.svg);
  width: 32px;
  height: 35px;
  top: -50px;
  right: -50px;
}

.smartphoto-nav {
  z-index: 99999;
}

.smartphoto-arrows {
  top: 90%;
  z-index: 999999;
}

.smartphoto-arrow-right,
.smartphoto-arrow-left {
  background-color: $white;
  height: 67px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.smartphoto-arrow-right {
  a {
    background-image: none !important;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    &::before {
      content: "";
      background-image: url(../images/icon/arrow-slide-after.svg);
      position: absolute;
      width: 8px;
      height: 11px;
    }
  }
}

.smartphoto-arrow-left {
  a {
    background-image: none !important;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    &::before {
      content: "";
      background-image: url(../images/icon/arrow-slide-before.svg);
      position: absolute;
      width: 8px;
      height: 11px;
    }
  }
}

.smartphoto-nav a {
  opacity: 1;
  &.current {
    border: 4px solid $red;
  }
}

.smartphoto-nav li {
  width: 92px;
  height: 63px;
}

.smartphoto-nav ul {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

ul li {
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}

li:before {
  content: "";
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/smartphoto@1.1.0/css/smartphoto.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-bLT0Qm9VnAYZDflyKcBaQ2gg0hSYNQrJ8RilYldYQ1FxQYoCLtUjuuRuZo+fjqhx/qtq/1itJ0C2ejDxltZVFg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/smartphoto@1.1.0/js/smartphoto.min.js"></script>

<div class="article__gallery-images">
  <a href="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542311908-d0f7aef6a97f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" class="gallery-article article__gallery-item" data-caption="Caption 1" data-id="id-1">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542311908-d0f7aef6a97f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" data-group="group">
  </a>
  <div style="display: none;">
    <a href="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542311908-d0f7aef6a97f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" class="gallery-article article__gallery-item" data-caption="Caption 2" data-id="id-2">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542311908-d0f7aef6a97f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" data-group="group">
    </a>
    <a href="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542311908-d0f7aef6a97f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" class="gallery-article article__gallery-item" data-caption="Caption 3" data-id="id-3">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542311908-d0f7aef6a97f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" data-group="group">
    </a>
    <a href="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542311908-d0f7aef6a97f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" class="gallery-article article__gallery-item" data-caption="Caption 2" data-id="id-2">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542311908-d0f7aef6a97f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" data-group="group">
    </a>
    <a href="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542311908-d0f7aef6a97f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" class="gallery-article article__gallery-item" data-caption="Caption 3" data-id="id-3">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542311908-d0f7aef6a97f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" data-group="group">
    </a>
    <a href="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542311908-d0f7aef6a97f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" class="gallery-article article__gallery-item" data-caption="Caption 2" data-id="id-2">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542311908-d0f7aef6a97f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" data-group="group">
    </a>
    <a href="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542311908-d0f7aef6a97f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" class="gallery-article article__gallery-item" data-caption="Caption 3" data-id="id-3">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542311908-d0f7aef6a97f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" data-group="group">
    </a>
    <a href="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542311908-d0f7aef6a97f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" class="gallery-article article__gallery-item" data-caption="Caption 2" data-id="id-2">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542311908-d0f7aef6a97f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" data-group="group">
    </a>
    <a href="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542311908-d0f7aef6a97f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" class="gallery-article article__gallery-item" data-caption="Caption 3" data-id="id-3">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542311908-d0f7aef6a97f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" data-group="group">
    </a>
    <a href="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542311908-d0f7aef6a97f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" class="gallery-article article__gallery-item" data-caption="Caption 2" data-id="id-2">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542311908-d0f7aef6a97f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" data-group="group">
    </a>
    <a href="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542311908-d0f7aef6a97f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" class="gallery-article article__gallery-item" data-caption="Caption 3" data-id="id-3">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542311908-d0f7aef6a97f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" data-group="group">
    </a>
    <a href="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542311908-d0f7aef6a97f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" class="gallery-article article__gallery-item" data-caption="Caption 2" data-id="id-2">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542311908-d0f7aef6a97f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" data-group="group">
    </a>
    <a href="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542311908-d0f7aef6a97f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" class="gallery-article article__gallery-item" data-caption="Caption 3" data-id="id-3">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542311908-d0f7aef6a97f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" data-group="group">
    </a>
     <a href="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542311908-d0f7aef6a97f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" class="gallery-article article__gallery-item" data-caption="Caption 3" data-id="id-3">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542311908-d0f7aef6a97f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" data-group="group">
    </a>
    <a href="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542311908-d0f7aef6a97f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" class="gallery-article article__gallery-item" data-caption="Caption 2" data-id="id-2">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542311908-d0f7aef6a97f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" data-group="group">
    </a>
    <a href="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542311908-d0f7aef6a97f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" class="gallery-article article__gallery-item" data-caption="Caption 3" data-id="id-3">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542311908-d0f7aef6a97f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" data-group="group">
    </a>
    <a href="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542311908-d0f7aef6a97f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" class="gallery-article article__gallery-item" data-caption="Caption 2" data-id="id-2">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542311908-d0f7aef6a97f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" data-group="group">
    </a>
    <a href="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542311908-d0f7aef6a97f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" class="gallery-article article__gallery-item" data-caption="Caption 3" data-id="id-3">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542311908-d0f7aef6a97f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" data-group="group">
    </a>
    <a href="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542311908-d0f7aef6a97f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" class="gallery-article article__gallery-item" data-caption="Caption 2" data-id="id-2">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542311908-d0f7aef6a97f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" data-group="group">
    </a>
    <a href="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542311908-d0f7aef6a97f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" class="gallery-article article__gallery-item" data-caption="Caption 3" data-id="id-3">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542311908-d0f7aef6a97f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" data-group="group">
    </a>
    <a href="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542311908-d0f7aef6a97f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" class="gallery-article article__gallery-item" data-caption="Caption 2" data-id="id-2">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542311908-d0f7aef6a97f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" data-group="group">
    </a>
    <a href="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542311908-d0f7aef6a97f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" class="gallery-article article__gallery-item" data-caption="Caption 3" data-id="id-3">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542311908-d0f7aef6a97f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" data-group="group">
    </a>
    <a href="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542311908-d0f7aef6a97f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" class="gallery-article article__gallery-item" data-caption="Caption 2" data-id="id-2">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542311908-d0f7aef6a97f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" data-group="group">
    </a>
    <a href="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542311908-d0f7aef6a97f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" class="gallery-article article__gallery-item" data-caption="Caption 3" data-id="id-3">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542311908-d0f7aef6a97f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" data-group="group">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The demo doesn't show the thumbnail in the screen short. Can you update it so it will reflect the issue?

Comment: @Mosh Feu Fixed the code. If you look at the last picture that is at the bottom and click on the next one, the active picture will not be displayed and it will disappear. It is essential that it is always visible and not lost. Specifically, you should switch between the top and bottom images.

Comment: Click on the image indeed open the carousel but sill not the same as the picture. I can click on the most right image and see it well. https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cr0c.png

Comment: We need to remove the scroll and make the picture switch and move by itself.

Comment: So you need a new feature for Smartphoto, it's not that something is not working as expected. This is bigger than I thought. Probably have no time for this.. Sorry..